# Will my new Xiaomi RedMi Note 2 prime work for LTE network?

Tags: mobile-network, 4g, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I just bought this smartphone, and I am confused if it will work in my area and if it will work for 4G and LTE. I called the support of T-Mobile, and they said if it configured correctlly, it will have LTE for 2100 frequency in LA area, but many posts online say the opposite.

Device:
http://www.gearbest.com/cell-phones/pp_229219.html#customer_review

Frequencies for this device:

```
2G: GSM 900/1800/1900MHz 
3G: WCDMA 850/900/1900/2100MHz 
4G: FDD-LTE 1800/2100/2600MHz
```

T-MOBILE [frequencies](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-4988):

```
**T-Mobile network coverage**

Created by tmo_ian on Oct 16, 2012 8:55 AM. Last modified by tmo_kim on Oct 13, 2015 8:26 AM.
Voice over LTE (VoLTE)
VoLTE (Voice over LTE) allows you to place and receive calls on our LTE data network. Phone calls are connected with a clear and rich experience. You never know when you might need to check Facebook while talking to your mom and sharing your Mobile Hotspot with your friends. All of this, on our amazingly fast 4G LTE network. Here's some of the highlights:

Switch between 4G VoLTE and Wi-Fi without dropping a call!
Enjoy crystal-clear calls with our new HD Voice service.
Browse the web with speed while on a call.
Placing a call connects twice as fast.

4G LTE
T-Mobile's advanced 4G LTE network is smoking fast! With incredible speed, you can do more using our nationwide 4G LTE network. 4G LTE delivers up to 50% faster speeds then 3G. If you're in an area served by 4G LTE, you can expect blazing fast speeds because of our expanded capacity. Check out our coverage map to see all the places we have 4G LTE.*

Frequencies: Band 2 (1900 MHz), Band 4 (1700/2100 MHz), Band 12 (700 MHz)

4G (HSPA+)
With 4G, theoretical maximum download speeds range from 21 Mbps up to 42 Mbps. You can take advantage of incredibly fast download speeds, and even use voice and data services at the same time.

Frequencies: Band 2 (1900 MHz), Band 4 (1700/2100 MHz)

L700
This is also referred to low-band spectrum, it adds increased building penetration as well as covering greater distances. This will be used in metro areas to improve in-building coverage and in rural areas to improve our LTE footprint.

Frequencies: Band 12 (700 MHz)

L1900
L1900 is being used primarily to update our current 2G towers to LTE. Many of our current LTE devices already support L1900 band 2. Check out this device list for phones that are compatible.

Frequencies: Band 2 (1900 MHz)

3G (HSPA)
With 3G, theoretical maximum download of 14 Mbps. With 3G, you can use voice and data services simultaneously.

Frequencies: Band 4 (1700/2100 MHz)

2G (GSM, GPRS, and EDGE)
EDGE, our enhanced 2G service, delivers a theoretical maximum download speed of 236 kbps. GPRS, our 2G service, delivers a theoretical maximum download speed of 114 kbps. Typical speeds are between 35 kbps and 45 kbps. Keep in mind, voice and data services cannot work simultaneously when on GPRS or EDGE.**

Frequencies: Band 2 (1900 MHz)

Requirements
It's important to use a device capable of the network type you desire, and you should be in a location that has cellular network coverage. Check out our coverage map to see what areas we service, and check out Phones & Devices for device specifications.
```

Should I return this phone ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Keep the phone, it's all right. You will get 4G if your APN settings are configured correctly and you have a working 4G plan.

But for your information, what T-Mobile calls "4G" is actually a kind of enhanced 3G (HSPA+) whereas "real" 4G is LTE.

This phone can access 4G in India, on a hardware basis it should be capable of accessing 4G in the US, unless you got a carrier-locked handset.